# How to enable and Disable Months by selecting present or future year

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new in the Programing world,

I want to set if you have selected the current year then passed months have to be disabled. but when you choose next year or further year, then Months should be available 1 to 12.

for example,
Today is March 2021,
then Option 1 and 2 should be disabled in the select option.

But If I choose 2022 in a year then Months from 1 to 12 should enable...

```js
var i, currentYear, startYear, endYear, newOption, dropdownYear;
dropdownYear = document.getElementById("expyear");
currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
startYear = currentYear;
endYear = currentYear + 14;

for (i = startYear; i <= endYear; i++) {
    newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = i;
    newOption.label = i;

    dropdownYear.appendChild(newOption);
}
```

```html
<label for="expmonth">Exp Month</label>
<select style="width: auto; display: inline;" name="expmonth" id="expmonth">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
 </select>
<label for="expyear">Exp Year</label>
<select style="width: auto; display: inline;" name="expyear" id="expyear"> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by listening to the change event of the year.

Once the value in the year is changed, check for

1. If the selected value of year is the current year.
2. Iterate over all the options of the month and check if the value in the option in less than the current month.

```js
var i, currentYear, startYear, endYear, newOption, dropdownYear;
dropdownYear = document.getElementById("expyear");
currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
startYear = currentYear;
endYear = currentYear + 14;

for (i = startYear; i <= endYear; i++) {
    newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = i;
    newOption.label = i;

    dropdownYear.appendChild(newOption);
}

var year_select = document.getElementById('expyear');
var month_select = document.getElementById('expmonth');

var today = new Date();
var yearChanged = function () {
  month_select.value = 12; // reset the month to 12 ( to be safe )
  month_select.querySelectorAll('option').forEach(function (op) {
    if (year_select.value == today.getFullYear() && op.getAttribute('value') < today.getMonth() + 1) {
      op.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'); // disable the option as it is less than current month and year.
    }
    else {
      op.removeAttribute('disabled'); // enabled the date as greater than the current month or year.
    }
  });
};

yearChanged(); // call the function initally to set the disabled options for current year.

year_select.addEventListener('change', yearChanged, true); // event listening.
```

```html
<label for="expmonth">Exp Month</label>
<select style="width: auto; display: inline;" name="expmonth" id="expmonth">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
 </select>
<label for="expyear">Exp Year</label>
<select style="width: auto; display: inline;" name="expyear" id="expyear"> 
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you Adarsh, This is really helpful and easy to understanding.

Comment: Thank you, please mark as the answer if this worked for you